# Add div on top of svg chart (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have a bar chart where I'd like to add a round red x at the top right of each bar to show that the user can remove a specific bar, but I am having trouble figuring out how to add this. This is what I like the final image to be like, but also repeating on the other four bars as well.[image: End goal]

I have provided a jsfiddle along with the JS code that does everything else I like the graph to do, except no red x.

[DemoCode](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsolis/nx97oco5/5/)

```
    // graph variables
    var xScale                 ,
        yScale                 ,
        xAxis                  ,
        yAxis                  ;

    // chart dimensions
    var margin   = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 70 },
        width    =  $('#chart').width() - margin.left - margin.right,
        height   =  $(window).height() / 3.5 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // color palette for graph
    var colors = [ '#4398B5', '#ADC4CC', '#92B06A', '#E09D2A', '#DE5F32' ];

    var data = [
        { id : 1, value : 100},
        { id : 2, value : 200},
        { id : 3, value : 300},
        { id : 4, value : 400},
        { id : 5, value : 500}
    ];

    // svg object for graph
    var svg;

    xScale = d3.scaleBand()
               .domain( d3.range( data.length ) )
               .range( [ 0, width ] )
               .padding( 0.1 );

    var yMax = d3.max( data, function( d ) {
        return d.value;
    });

    yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain( [ 0, yMax  ] )
               .range( [ height, 0 ] );


    xAxis = d3.axisBottom( xScale );
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft( yScale );

    var yTicks       = yAxis.ticks(5),
        yTicksFormat = yAxis.tickFormat( d3.format( '$,' ) );

    svg = d3.select( '#chart svg' )
                    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' +  ( width + margin.left + margin.right ) + ' ' + ( height  + margin.top + margin.bottom ) )
                    .attr('height', ( height + 'px' ) )
                    .attr('width', '100%')
                    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'none')
                    .append( 'g' )
                    .attr( 'transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')' );

    svg.selectAll( 'rect' )
       .data( data )
       .enter()
       .append( 'rect' )
           .attr('x', function ( d, i ) {
                return xScale( i );
           })
           .attr('y', function( d, i ) {
                return yScale( 0 );
           })
           .attr( 'height', function( d ) {
               return height - yScale( 0 );
           })
           .attr( 'width', xScale.bandwidth() )
           .attr('fill', function( d, i ) {
               return colors[ i ];
           })
           .transition()
           .duration( 1500 )
           .attr( 'y', function( d, i ) {
               return yScale( d.value );
           })
           .attr( 'height', function( d ) {
               return height - yScale( d.value );
           })
           .on('end', function( d, i ) {
                /*Insert this button somewhere
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>*/

           });

    svg.append( 'g' )
       .attr( 'class', 'yAxis' )
       .attr( 'transform', 'translate(0, ' + (-1) + ')')
       .call( yAxis );
```

I would guess to insert the red x after each bars `.on('end', function...)` function is called.

The actual red x itself would be

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>*/
```

And the CSS for it would be

```
    .btn-circle {
        width: 19px;
        height: 19px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1px 0;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 0.1;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
```

which is provided in the JSFiddle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: do you need the X to grow with the bars? or just appear at the end of the animation?

Comment: Sorry, should if mentioned that I think it's okay if the icon stays the same size just as long as it appears at the top right. In case I did want it to grow I imagine I could place it in a responsive div and that be okay, but im not sure.

Comment: I meant - do you need to animate them - raise with bars, appear at the end of SVG loading, or just be there constantly?

Comment: Oh my mistake, yes I like them to start at the bottom if possible and rise up with the bar.

Comment: Hmm, This SVG changes size depending on the window height. Is it not going to be fixed size?

Comment: The height will stay the same but the width is expected to be responsive.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nx97oco5/7/
I gotta go to bed, that's the best I could think of... Problem is - the svg changes shape when width of the window is changed, skips the width at certain window size, also renders different height when you change the height of the window.

Try resizing the jsfiddle result window and run the script when resized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of appending a `div` (or any other HTML element, which you can't append to an SVG), it's easier to append an SVG circle element and an SVG text element, imitating a button:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll('.circles')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle').attr("cursor", "pointer")
    .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
        return xScale(i)+ xScale.bandwidth();
     })
    .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
        return yScale(0);
    })
    .attr('fill', "red").attr("r", 8)
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
         return yScale( d.value );
    });

var xtext = svg.selectAll('.xtext')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', function (d, i) {
        return xScale( i )+ xScale.bandwidth();
    })
    .attr('y', function( d, i ) {
        return yScale( 0 );
    })
    .attr('fill', "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .text("x")
    .transition()
    .duration( 1500 )
    .attr( 'y', function( d, i ) {
       return yScale( d.value );
    });
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dcb8ok9j/

PS: this only adds the circles, you'll have to add the behaviour separately.